The meaning of "by" in "swear by God"

I swear by God that I will speak the truth. (Source)

(The writer might be Japanese.)
What does by mean?
"Swear to God" is understandable to me, but I don't know what "swear by God" means. I think that the only possible meaning of by is "in proximity to" among various senses of "by" given in the Merriam-Webster Dictionary. Still, I guess that the actual meaning of by is "before" or "in the presence of".

By: ​used when swearing to mean ‘in the name of’ I swear by Almighty God… Oxford Learner's Dictionaries

Thank you, Michael Harvey. I looked at that definition, but couldn't understand exactly what "in the name of" means in the example sentence.

'In the name of' is used by someone claiming the power or authority of a more powerful person, e.g. open this door in the name of the king! I order you to stop in the name of the law! In the name of God I declare you are married.

So in the name of God and with the witness or sanction of God have the same meaning, right?

More or less, yes. Of course, the existence of the king is a matter of fact, but the existence of God is one of belief.

Honestly, sentences like "In the name of God I declare you are married" sound slightly odd to me although I guess It would probably sound natural to native speakers of French/German/Spanish/etc. English is still alien to me, probably because I can not think in English. I am dejected with my English.

This is a standard expression in English. By has a wide range of meanings, and one of them is:


with the witness or sanction of
swear by all that is holy


So I swear by God that I will speak the truth means:

I swear, with God as my witness, that I will speak the truth.

EDIT:
For those familiar with the bible, Matthew 5:33-37 is a well known example of this usage. Jesus is teaching his followers that obedience to the law is not a matter of following external and arbitrary rules, but a matter of being righteous at a deep spiritual level. One example he discusses is the Jewish habit of swearing by particular objects in creation or in the temple: If you are utterly honest, he says, you will only need to say "yes" or "no" and that will be sufficient.

33 “Again, you have heard that it was said to the people long ago, ‘Do not break your oath, but fulfill to the Lord the vows you have made.’ 34 But I tell you, do not swear an oath at all: either by heaven, for it is God’s throne; 35 or by the earth, for it is his footstool; or by Jerusalem, for it is the city of the Great King. 36 And do not swear by your head, for you cannot make even one hair white or black. 37 All you need to say is simply ‘Yes’ or ‘No’; anything beyond this comes from the evil one.


Thank you, Peter Kirkpatrick. I had looked at that definition, but couldn't understand the example. The "all that is holy" seems to me to be an inanimate thing. Can it mean "God"?

All that is holy can include God, but can also refer to anything else considered holy by the person saying it. A court witness might swear by the Bible to tell the truth. For those who know the Bible there is a famous example of this usage in the Sermon on the Mount, which I will add to the answer.

You can swear by (in the name of) or on anything that you regard as sacred or especially precious, including your life or your mother's life. "All that is holy" implies "everything that I, as a Christian, regard as holy". People giving evidence in courts of law traditionally swear on the Bible that their evidence is true.

Thank you, Peter and Kate. I would like to know what the core meaning of the preposition "by" is.

There is an ancient tradition that invoking the name of someone or something sacred when you make a promise or declare that something is true, makes that promise or statement especially strong. That's what 'swearing by' something means.
